# How to use cudaMallocManaged with an object with constructor

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to use CUDA managed memory in combination with an object that i create via constructor.

```
struct A {
    A(float x) : x(x) {}
    float x;
}

__global__ void myKernel(A *a) {
    printf("%f", a->x);
}

int main() {
    A *a;
    cudaMallocManaged(&a, sizeof(A));
    a->x = 42.f;        // This works
    // a = new a(42.f); // This obviously doesn't because a doesn't point
                        // to managed memory now.
    myKernel<<<1,1>>>(a);
}
```

Using the constructor instead of the direct initialization `a->x = ...` would be convenient for more complex classes that `A`.

I could of course create the object `a` with the constructor and use the "normal" cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy as follows.

```
A a(42.f);
A *d_a;
cudaMalloc(&d_a, sizeof(A));
cudaMemcpy(d_a, &a, sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Is there any possibility to use the managed memory and still initialize the objects with their constructor?

Comment: You could overload `new` and `delete`. That will  introduce complexities of their own

Comment: [This blog article](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/) demonstrates how to overload `new` for a specific class, so that you can allocate using managed memory.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, that should be the answer. Thanks for your comment, it helps me a lot. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed by Mark Harris [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/), you can overload the `new` and `delete` operators for your class so that instances will be allocated and deallocated via the managed memory APIs, rather than by the host standard library memory allocation. Doing this means you can't call `new` in device code for any class you define this way.

One very convenient design pattern for this (again full credit to the Mark Harris blog for the idea), is to define a class which only contains suitable `new` and `delete` operators, and then inherit from it when you define your own classes which will use unified memory. Like this:

```
class Managed {
public:
  void *operator new(size_t len) {
    void *ptr;
    cudaMallocManaged(&ptr, len);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return ptr;
  }

  void operator delete(void *ptr) {
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaFree(ptr);
  }
};

class A : public Managed
{
public:
    A(float x) : x(x) {}
    float x;
}

// ....

A *a = new A(42.f);
```

Note that ideally you should also define assignment operators for your data class so that copy construction and other useful C++ idioms will work correctly.